# Handling SerializationException in kafka native apis

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is there any way to handle to handle serialization exception that occur at consumer side while consuming messages from a Kafka topic using native kafka apis. I found that [this](https://jonboulineau.me/blog/kafka/dealing-with-bad-records-in-kafka) article provides a hacky way by parsing the exception message and moving ahead of the offset. However this approach can also lead to loss of messages if we are polling more than once record at once and one of the record was malformed.

Comment: That link shows exactly what you want - wrap the deserializer class and handle the exception. As long as you seek to offset+1 and disable auto commits, you're not skipping anything else or losing data

Comment: @OneCricketeer The approach of wrapping deserializer class would require me to wrap every deserailizer class that I use (standard or custom), hence I was inclined towards the second approach mentioned there where we can catch SerailizationException from poll() call. However lets say in an interval there are 5 messages that are read in which 3rd one is corrupt. Then I would lose 1st and 2nd messages as well since poll() would get all these messages in batches and raise exception only once. I can set poll() to read only one message at a time but that would slow down things.

Comment: As mentioned, if you are manually committing offsets, you have full control over what is or isn't skipped. If you've processed 1 and 2, then message 3 of 5 is corrupt, you'd commit and seek to 4, then re-poll message 4 onwards

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes I am going this way but I wanted to understand if there is any other way too.

Comment: Maybe, but any other way you find will still seek past the offset of the message causing exception. If you're looking to avoid parsing the exception message, I'd say that's a limitation of the SerializationException class itself to not pull that data into some `RecordMetadata` field

Comment: Exactly I wanted to avoid manual parsing but I am going forward with this for now. Thanks for the help.